# Integration of $\int \frac{1}{x^2 \ln x } dx $

Tags: calculus

How can I get this integral?

$$\int \frac{1}{x^2 \ln x } dx $$

I tried integration by parts but it only got worse. I don't know if there's something we can do to $\ln x $ so it's easier to integrate. Thanks.

Comment: It is not solvable in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: I agree with @user1337 . This integral can be stated in terms of the exponential integral as 
$$\operatorname{Ei}(-\log(x))+c$$
But this doesn't have an elementary representation.

Comment: You can represent the result as a power series, though.

Comment: It can also be calculated as $-\mathrm{Li}(1/x)$